# Passing data to View using ViewModel in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

**SOLUTION:**

```
ParticipantsWithData = await _context.Participants.Select(p => new ParticipantWithData {
    Participant = p,
    Team = p.Teams,
    FirstWeight = p.ParticipantData.Where(pd => pd.ParticipantId == p.Id).OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
    LastWeight = p.ParticipantData.Where(pd => pd.ParticipantId == p.Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToListAsync();
```

And then the model:

```
public class ParticipantWithData {

    public Participant Participant { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public ParticipantData FirstWeight { get; set; }
    public ParticipantData LastWeight { get; set; }

}
```

That way I can do `x.FirstWeight.Date` or `x.FirstWeight.Weight` when looping through Participants (see the ParticipantData model below),

---

**QUESTION:**

How can I use this in my view?

```
var query = await _context.Participants.Select(p => new {
    Participant = p,
    Team = p.Teams,
    FirstWeight = p.ParticipantData.OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
    LastWeight = p.ParticipantData.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToListAsync();
```

If possible, I'd like to make it a strongly typed model, but I don't know how to do that. All I've tried so far doesn't work.

The Participant model:

```
public class Participant {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public Team Teams { get; set; }

    public IList<ParticipantData> ParticipantData { get; set; }

}
```

The ParticipantData model:

```
public class ParticipantData {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public double? Weight { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Guid ParticipantId { get; set; }

    public Participant Participants { get; set; }

}
```

The new model I'm working on:

```
public class ParticipantWithData {

    public Participant Participant { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public ParticipantData ParticipantData { get; set; }

    public double? FirstWeight { get; set; }
    public double? LastWeight { get; set; }

}
```

Maybe I'm way off..?

Comment: Add your `ParticipantData` model to the question please!

Comment: Please see my updated question with more details. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your `ParticipantViewModel` as follows:

```
public class ParticipantViewModel
{
    public Participant Participant { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public double? FirstWeight { get; set; }
    public double? LastWeight { get; set; }

}
```

Then in the query:

```
var query = await _context.Participants.Inculde(p => p.Teams)
                  .Include(p => p.ParticipantData).Select(p => new ParticipantViewModel 
                   {
                       Participant = p,
                       Team = p.Teams,
                       FirstWeight = p.ParticipantData.Select(pd => pd.Weight).OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
                       LastWeight = p.ParticipantData.Select(pd => pd.Weight).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault()
                   }).ToListAsync();
```

Note: I didn't see your `ParticipantData` model but I have answered with assumption so there may be some changes according to your actual data and requirement.

Comment: Thank you! I think we're almost there. But in the "FirstWeight = p.ParticipantData.Select(pd => pd.Weight)..." I get an "'ParticipantData' does not contain a definition for 'Select'..."? I know I've set it as a double? in the model, but if possible I would rather have it as an object, so I can get both the weight and the date.

Comment: It would be great if you can share your code with remote access! So that I can see the real scenario.

Comment: I can't give you access to the code as it contains sensitive data, sorry. What else do you want me to show you for you to be able to help?

Comment: Actually your provided code is confusing. So its hard to guess what to do!